# Why does my recursive program suddenly stop working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, recursion

I have the following recursive code that in first line of input takes any positive integers in ascending order with space between each two numbers. And second line takes a non negative integer. The code then writes all possible combinations with repetition of writing the second number with the numbers from the first line in descending order. This code works, however if I have some bigger numbers the code runs and then without any error stops working without finishing the task. What could be the issue please ? I have tried increasing recursion limit and tried decreasing memory usage.

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(15000)

secondline = input().split()
coins=[]
for i in secondline:
    coins.append(int(i))
summ=int(input())

def can_be_paid(coins,summ):
    if summ == 0:
        return False
    local_summ = summ
    counter=0
    while local_summ > 0:
        if local_summ >= coins[counter]:
            local_summ-=coins[counter]
            if local_summ == 0:
                return True
        elif counter < len(coins)-1:
            counter+=1
        elif len(coins) > 1:
            counter = 0
            del coins[0]
            local_summ=summ
        else:
            return False

def can_be_paid_with_less_coins(value,coins):
    could_possibly_be_paid_with_less=True
    local_value=value
    counter=0
    coins = [coin for coin in coins if value > coin]
    while could_possibly_be_paid_with_less:
        if len(coins) == 0:
            return False
        if local_value >= coins[counter]:
            local_value-=coins[counter]
            if local_value == 0:
                return True
        elif counter < len(coins)-1:
            counter+=1
        else:
            del coins[0]
            counter = 0
            local_value = value

def pay_with_least_coins(value,coins):
    local_value=value
    paid=[]
    counter=0
    while local_value > 0:
        if local_value >= coins[counter]:
            local_value-=coins[counter]
            paid.append(coins[counter])
        elif counter < len(coins)-1:
            counter+=1
        else:
            paid=[]
            counter=0
            local_value=value
            del coins[0]
    return paid

def pay_with_more_coins(previous_coins,coins):
    value=0
    for i in previous_coins:
    value+=i
    coins = [coin for coin in coins if coin < previous_coins[0]]
    the_rest = pay_with_least_coins(value,coins)
    return the_rest

def pay(coins,previouscoins):
    for i in previouscoins:
        print (i, end=' ')
    print()
    for i in range(len(previouscoins)):
        if can_be_paid_with_less_coins(previouscoins[-i-1],coins):
            negative_index=i+1
            break
        elif i == len(previouscoins)-1:
            return
    new_coins=previouscoins[:len(previouscoins)-negative_index]
    the_rest_of_previous_coins=previouscoins[-negative_index:]
    new_coins += pay_with_more_coins(the_rest_of_previous_coins,coins)
    pay(coins,new_coins)

if can_be_paid(coins,summ):
   pay(coins,pay_with_least_coins(summ,coins))
```

for examlpe this input:

5 4 3 2 1

20

works fine

ouput starts with: 5 5 5 5

then goes like: 5 5 5 4 1

and all the way to: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 1 (20x1)

for example this does not work:10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

100

it goes like the example before but then without any error stops at:

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 5 5 5 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
although it should end with this:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 .... 1 (100x1)

Comment: Can you give an example of a number that breaks this and a number that doesn't? Can you also share what you find when you step through the code in a debugger and put breakpoints on lines you expect to be reached?

Comment: The problem is because `pay()` keeps calling itself for some reason. Since there's only one `return` statement in it, it's probably because the logic involved in deciding to do that or not is wrong. You will have to figure out why that happens to resolve the issue.

Comment: But even if I delete the return condition and the return the program just stops working after a while wihtout any error or anything